# The user to use special characters when creating a password

Tags: python, if-statement, jupyter-notebook, password-protection, any

I want the user to use special characters when creating a password.(at least 1)
Example:

```
special_character= list(string.punctuation)
password=input("enter password:")
if any(i not in password for i in special_character):
    print("You should add a special character for creating strong password!")
```

it will be like this but it doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `all(...)`, or alternatively, use `not any(...)` but without the `not` in the list comprehension (this is better because `not` gets run less times overall, making it marginally more efficient). This is what the code would look like:

```py
special_characters = list(string.punctuation)
password = input("Enter password: ")
if not any(i in password for i in special_characters):
    print("You should add a special character for creating strong password!")
```